# how to override elm json decoders?

Tags: json, elm, decoding, elm-0.18

In our project we use [standard json encoders](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Encode) to encode our elm data models to json. As a result, I want to get a string that would look like a list of objects `[{..}, {..}]`, but I get a rather unexpected result: an object where the keys are the index of the elements, and the values are the objects that I want to encode, that look like:

```
{
    "0": {"a":"b"}, 
    "1": {"c":"d"}
}
```

How I can override my encoders in order to get the desired list of objects?
Our json encoders:

```
memberListEncoder : List Member -> Encode.Value
memberListEncoder memberList =
    Encode.list (List.map encodeMember memberList)
```

and

```
encodeMember : Member -> Encode.Value
encodeMember member =
    Encode.object
        [ ( "firstName", Encode.string member.firstName.value )
        , ( "lastName", Encode.string member.lastName.value )
        ]
```

Comment: Can you include your definition for the `Member` type?

Comment: This seems like a question specific to Elm 0.18, so I added a tag for that. Please correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem in Ellie (which uses 0.19). Could you provide a reproducible example including the definition of `Member`, the specific input value and how you convert the resulting `Encode.Value` to a string?

Comment: Also, this looks a bit like how Firefox represents arrays of objects in the developer console. How do you observe the output?

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming Elm 0.19**

While I have not yet seen your `Member` definition, I think the problem is that you do not need to use `List.map` in your `memberListEncoder`. The following should suffice:

```elm
memberListEncoder : List Member -> Encode.Value
memberListEncoder memberList =
    Encode.list encodeMember memberList
```

Comment: You answer applies to Elm 0.19, but I think this is 0.18 where you do need to use `List.map`: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Encode#list